# Getting values of mutiple entry widgets in one form (Tkinter)

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have seen answers on questions regarding one entry - which works as I tried 
But I want to know if there is a possibility to Get values from multiple entries by one button press.
The scenario is building a form - like in the code below which asks the user to enter multiple parameters. Then, by clicking on the button - some operation could be made with this data (Print\write to file etc.. )
The code below is a form I'm trying to produce (my first python prog - for checking possibilites etc.) 
and I can't seem to be able to get the values which have been entered in the form 
The main purpose is to be able to write the values entered to a file. 
But i'll satisfy in just making the code work for printing the values :-)
I'm really new to python (3) and will apreciate any help :-)
the code :

```
def CreateUser():
# Define Confirmation Function (For checking option - print, Generally i would like the values to be written to file)
def Confirmation():
    UserInput.set(UserNo_entered.get())
    print(UserInput.get())
```

# The Writing to file I would like to perform
   #  f = open(ProgramPath+"\Users.txt", "a+")
   #  f.write(UserNo + "," + FName + "," + LName + "," + Telephone + "," + Street + "," +\
   #  HouseNo + "," + Apartment + "," + Country)
   #  f.close()

```
win = tk.Tk()
#Window Title
win.wm_title("CREATE USER")
#Window size
win.wm_geometry("500x300")


ttk.Label(win, text="\n").grid(column=0, row=1) #Empty Line
ttk.Label(win, text="Enter User Details Below:",font=("David",12,"bold","underline")).grid(column=0, row=1,padx=0, pady=10,sticky="W") #Pad x,y for spaces between lines
# User No.
ttk.Label(win, text="User No.:",font=("David",12)).grid(column=0,row=3,padx=0, pady=10,sticky="W") #sticky="W" for aligning to the left
UserNo=StringVar()
UserNo_entered= tk.Entry(win, width=12, textvariable=UserNo, cursor="pencil").grid(row=3,padx=50)
#UserNo_entered= tk.Entry(win, width=12,textvariable=UserNo, cursor="pencil").grid(row=3,padx=50)
ttk.Label(win,text="* Mandatory",font=("Miryam fixed",10),foreground="red").grid(row=3,column=1,sticky="W")
#First Name
ttk.Label(win, text="First Name:",font=("David",12)).grid(column=0, row=4,padx=0, pady=10,sticky="W")
FName = tk.StringVar()
FName_entered = ttk.Entry(win, width=12, textvariable=FName, cursor="pencil").grid(row=4,padx=100)
ttk.Label(win,text="* Mandatory",font=("Miryam fixed",10),foreground="red").grid(row=4,column=1,sticky="W")
#Last Name
ttk.Label(win, text="Last Name:",font=("David",12)).grid(column=0, row=5,padx=0, pady=10,sticky="W")
LName = tk.StringVar()
LName_entered = ttk.Entry(win, width=12, textvariable=LName, cursor="pencil").grid(row=5,padx=100)
#Telephone
ttk.Label(win, text="Telephone:", font=("David", 12)).grid(column=1, row=5, padx=0, pady=10, sticky="W")
Telephone = tk.StringVar()
Telephone_entered = ttk.Entry(win, width=12, textvariable=Telephone, cursor="pencil").grid(row=5, column=1, padx=100)
#Street
ttk.Label(win, text="Street:", font=("David", 12)).grid(column=0, row=6, padx=0, pady=10, sticky="W")
Street = tk.StringVar()
Street_entered = ttk.Entry(win, width=12, textvariable=Street, cursor="pencil").grid(row=6, padx=100)
#House\Block no.
ttk.Label(win, text="House No.:", font=("David", 12)).grid(column=1, row=6, padx=0, pady=10, sticky="W")
HouseNo = tk.StringVar()
HouseNo_entered = ttk.Entry(win, width=12, textvariable=HouseNo, cursor="pencil").grid(row=6,column=1, padx=100)
# Apartment no.
ttk.Label(win, text="Apartment No.:", font=("David", 12)).grid(column=1, row=7, padx=0, pady=10, sticky="W")
Apartment = tk.StringVar()
Apartment_entered = ttk.Entry(win, width=12, textvariable=Apartment, cursor="pencil").grid(row=7, column=1, padx=100)
#Country
ttk.Label(win, text="Country:", font=("David", 12)).grid(column=0, row=7, padx=0, pady=10, sticky="W")
Country = tk.StringVar()
Country_entered = ttk.Entry(win, width=12, textvariable=Country, cursor="pencil").grid(row=7, column=0, padx=100)

ConfirmB=ttk.Button(win,text="CONFIRM",command=Confirmation)
ConfirmB.place(x=200,y=250)

win.mainloop(
```

Comment: This question is related to ```tkinter```. Please add ```Tkinter``` tag to your post to get the answers accordingly.

Comment: Please clarify your question as I do not see what the issue is.

You have a variable for each entry (ex Country).  get it's value with Country.get().  Do that with all your variable and you will have all your informations.

To clarify your question : 
What "other answer" have you seen. 
What exactly is not working. 
Do you get an error code. 
How are these two snips of code related : is the big one the CreateUser function?

Comment: Hi, well A. I need to know where to put the variable.Get line . I have tried to put it under the 'Confirmation' Function which didn't work. I get a "PY_VAR0" etc, all the time and not the value entered i nthe field. B. The other answers are answers from threads on the same topics. I hvae managed to run the scripts on those answers, but when trying to integrate it into my code - it did not work.

Comment: Well, after digging and trying a bit I have found the solution : First, i got rid of the StringVar variables. but The real problem was because I have 'Shortened' the line of the entry with .grid at the end instead putting the grid in different line. That what was intefering the .Get function to work.